# How do I monitor a fragment change?

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

As I am developing a SDK, I can only implement code in **Application.class**.
Now I know the Android API:

```
application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(activityLifecycleCallbacks)
```

and

```
fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(fragmentLifecycleCallbacks, true)
```

But it doesn't work as `onFragmentResumed` won't be called when I switch to different fragment

Comment: pass true for `recursive` try.

Comment: @Jaymin Thanks~ I have tried that a few minutes ago. Unfortunately, the callback such as `onFragmentPaused()` function will only be called when the corresponding fragment displayed for the first time.

Comment: It will be called because The system calls this method as the first indication that the user is leaving the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

in kotlin, create a class like so

```
object YourClass: FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks(), Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {}
```

in application class put the following in onCreate()

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(YourClass)
```

in YourClass put the following

```
override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity){(activity as BaseActivity).supportFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(YourClass, true)}
```

where BaseActivity is your custom class that implements AppCompatActivity()

Now, YourClass will hook itself into all activities in your android app, and will also receive onFragmentResumed() callback for all fragments in your app, every time.